# PHP - Values into any document file

Tags: php, file, document

my question is about PHP values into any file like:

```
.odt
.doc
.docx
.pdf
```

Is it possible to "transport" some of value from PHP e.x. $customer_name, into ready template of file? (.odt, .doc, .docx)

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  There are a few ways.  You can define headers and export the data into the file, or you can convert the entire readout into xml, and then handle it as you please.  (This way, you can use the same data in multiple formats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. For Word-like documents, you can use e.g. PHPWord: https://phpword.codeplex.com/

For PDF, there are plenty of libs. For easy and fast results, try fdpf: http://fpdf.de/